# Lucene: Accessing payloads of results of a query

Tags: lucene, token, payload

When I'm searching for a query in Lucene, I receive a list of documents as result. But how can I get the hits within those documents? I want to access the payload of those word, which where found by the query.

If your query contains only one term you can simply use `TermPositions` to access the payload of this term. But if you have a more complex query with Phrase Search, Proximity Search, ... you can't just search for the single terms in `TermPositions`.

I would like to receive a `List<Token>`, `TokenStream` or something similiar, which contains all the Tokens that were found by the query. Then I can iterate over the list and access the payload of each Token.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using SpanQueries. Nearly every Query can be expressed as SpanQuery. A SpanQuery gives access to the spans where the hit within a document is. Because the normal QueryParser doesn`t produce SpanQueries, I had to write my own parser which only creates SpanQueries. Another option would be the SurroundParser from Lucene-Contrib, which also creates SpanQueries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to start by looking at the Lucene Highlighter, as it highlights the matching terms in the document.

Comment: The Lucene Highlighter is doing a pretty good job but I still have problems accessing the payloads. I`m trying to write my own formatter. The Highlighter is passing a TokenGroup to the Formatter. When I call the getPayload() Function of the Tokens in the TokenGroup I always receive null. But when I access the payloads over TermPositions it`s working. Why is it not working for the Tokens? The entire TokenStream which I use for the highlighter doesn`t have the Payload Attribute. It`s always null.

Comment: I get the TokenStream with the following code: TokenStream tokenStream = TokenSources.getAnyTokenStream(searcher.getIndexReader(), id, "contents", analyzer); Do you have to do it differently?